# Inflating bytes in cpp

Tags: c++, zip, unzip

We have zipped(deflate) content in the form of byte[] which was uploaded using Java language (this is not gzip).

Now we want to unzip it in cpp.

Sample working unzip code in Java to unzip the content.

```
public byte[] deflate(@Nonnull final String text) {
    byte[] input = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] output = new byte[input.length + 100];
    deflater.reset();
    deflater.setInput(input);
    deflater.finish();
    int compressedDataLength = deflater.deflate(output);
    byte[] finalByteArray = new byte[compressedDataLength];
    System.arraycopy(output, 0, finalByteArray, 0, compressedDataLength);
    return finalByteArray;
  }
```

How can the same thing be achieved in cpp. Basically we want to inflate bytes in cpp which was deflated by java. There is no file, data input and output is directly in the form of bytes.

Any help in the code references, code snippets would be of great help.

Comment: I am sure zlib has documentation and examples: [https://zlib.net/](https://zlib.net/)

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please don't tag both if you're only working in one of them.

Comment: Plenty of zip libraries are available for C/C++, such as [libzip](https://libzip.org/), which can work with zips in memory

Comment: Also note that ZIP is really an archive file format, while deflate/inflate is a compression/uncompression algorithm.

Comment: And you say that "[t]here is no file, data input and output is directly in the form of bytes." But how are those "bytes" transmitted between the Java and the C++ program?

Comment: Lastly, this feels very much like a question "asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*" and such questions aren't [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.